# Java applet in JFrame graphics glitch?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

So I am trying to make a pinball game made as a applet load into a JFrame. The applet loads into it no problem but when i run it flickers and glitch out. Thanks in advance!

Jframe class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class PinBallGUI extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pinball");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,700);
        int height = 700;
        int width = 600;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PinBallGame temp = new PinBallGame();
        frame.add(temp);
        temp.init(width,height);
        temp.start();
        temp.run();
    }
}
```

Applet class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class PinBallGame extends Applet implements Runnable
{    
    Thread runner; 
    private Image Buffer;
    private Graphics gBuffer;
    int width,height;
    PinBallBall B1;
    PinBallPaddle P1,P2;
    PinBallRectangle R1,R2,R3,R4;
    PinBallRectangle[] rArray;
    boolean leftKey;
    boolean rightKey;
    boolean downKey;
    boolean spaceKey;
    int points;
    Random gen = new Random();
    public void init(int W,int H)
    {  
        width=W;
        height=H;
        Buffer=createImage(width,height);
        gBuffer=Buffer.getGraphics();
        B1 = new PinBallBall(-1,width-57,645);
        P1 = new PinBallPaddle(180,625,255,640);
        P2 = new PinBallPaddle(300,640,375,625);
        R1 = new PinBallRectangle(1,width-35,60,15,600);
        R2 = new PinBallRectangle(1,width-80,60,15,600);
        R3 = new PinBallRectangle(1,0,625,180,40);
        R4 = new PinBallRectangle(1,375,625,140,40);
        rArray = new PinBallRectangle[5];
        for(int i=0; i<rArray.length; i++)
        {
             rArray[i] = new       PinBallRectangle(-1,gen.nextInt(450),gen.nextInt(450),gen.nextInt(60),gen.nextInt(60));
        }
        int count = 0;
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        points = 0;
    }
    private class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter
    {
       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
       {
           switch(e.getKeyCode())
           {
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               leftKey = true;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               rightKey = true;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
               spaceKey = true;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
               downKey = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
       {
           switch(e.getKeyCode())
           {
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               leftKey = false;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               rightKey = false;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
               spaceKey = false;
               break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
               downKey = false;
               break;
            }
        }
    }   
    public void start()
    { 
        if (runner == null)
        {   
            runner = new Thread (this);
            runner.start();
        }
    }
    public void stop()
    {  
        runner = null;
    }
    public void run() 
    {  
        while(true)
        {
            update(gBuffer);
            if(leftKey){P1.moveLeftPaddle();}
            if(rightKey){P2.moveRightPaddle();}
            if(downKey){B1.launchBall(width,height);}
            repaint();
            try {runner.sleep(25);}
            catch (Exception e) { }   
            repaint();
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.black);
            gBuffer.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
            if((B1.getX() != width-57)||(B1.getY() != 645))
            {
                B1.movePinBallBall(width,height);
                B1.update();
            }
            R1.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            R2.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            R3.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            R4.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            P1.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            P2.ballCollision(B1);
            repaint();
            for(int i=0; i<rArray.length; i++)
            {
                rArray[i].ballCollision(B1);
                repaint();
            }
            for(int i=0; i<rArray.length; i++)
            {
                rArray[i].paint(gBuffer);
            }
            update(gBuffer);
            B1.paint(gBuffer);
            R1.paint(gBuffer);
            R2.paint(gBuffer);
            R3.paint(gBuffer);
            R4.paint(gBuffer);
            P1.paint(gBuffer);
            P2.paint(gBuffer);
            repaint();
            update(gBuffer);
        }//while(true)
    } //run    
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {  
        paint(g);
    } 
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(Buffer,0,0, this);
    }
}
```

I also have 3 other classes that are just for objects (ball, rectangle, paddle).
Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Applet loaded into a JFrame -- why would you want to do this?

Comment: You're mixing heavy and light weight components, which never seems to end well

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to either use JFrame and JPanel or Frame and Canvas instead of using a JFrame and an Applet. You can definitely mix and match components, but you'll probably encounter less bugs if you don't.

I generally find flickering to happen when you aren't using double buffering. Fro a JPanel you'll want to enable double buffering and for a Canvas there is a way to implement triple buffering if you really need to, but stick with a JPanel for most cases.